# Valgrind reports invalid read size of 8, but there are no memory leaks

Tags: c, valgrind, shellsort

The following is Valgrind's report:

```
==31109== Invalid read of size 8
==31109==    at 0x400D95: Array_Shellsort (in /home/shay/a/ashanbha/368summer/pa2/pa2)
==31109==    by 0x4006CB: main (in /home/shay/a/ashanbha/368summer/pa2/pa2)
==31109==  Address 0x5207238 is 8 bytes before a block of size 240 alloc'd
==31109==    at 0x4C29F73: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:309)
==31109==    by 0x400A92: Generate_2p3q_Seq (in /home/shay/a/ashanbha/368summer/pa2/pa2)
==31109==    by 0x400CBE: Array_Shellsort (in /home/shay/a/ashanbha/368summer/pa2/pa2)
==31109==    by 0x4006CB: main (in /home/shay/a/ashanbha/368summer/pa2/pa2)
==31109==
31970.000000
==31109==
==31109== HEAP SUMMARY:
==31109==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==31109==   total heap usage: 4 allocs, 4 frees, 9,376 bytes allocated
==31109==
==31109== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==31109==
==31109== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==31109== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

The following is the generate function:

```
  long *Generate_2p3q_Seq (int n, int *seq_size)
  {
    *seq_size = seqsize(n);
    long *sequence = malloc (sizeof(long) * *seq_size);
    printf("size: %d \n",*seq_size);
    sequence[0] = 1;
    int two = 0;
    int three = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < *seq_size; i++)
    {
      if ((sequence[two] * 2) > (sequence[three] * 3))
      {
        sequence[i] = sequence[three] * 3;
        three++;
      }
      else if ((sequence[two] * 2) < (sequence[three] * 3) )
      {
        sequence[i] = sequence[two] * 2;
        two++;
      }
      else
      {
        sequence[i] = sequence[two] * 2;
        three++;
        two++;
      }
    }
    return sequence;                                                                                          
  }
```

And the following is my shellsort function:

```
 void Array_Shellsort (long *array, int size, double *n_comp)
  {
    int seqsize = 0;
    long * sequencearray = Generate_2p3q_Seq(size,&seqsize);
      long interval = sequencearray[seqsize - 1];
    int i = 1;
    int in,out;
    long temp;
    *n_comp = 0;
    while (interval > 0)
    {
      for (out = interval; out < size; out++)
      {
        temp = array[out];
        in = out;
 
        while (in > interval - 1 && array[in - interval] >= temp)
        {
          array[in] = array[in - interval];
          in -= interval;
          (*n_comp)++;
        }
        array[in] = temp;
        (*n_comp)++;
      }
      i += 1;
      interval = sequencearray[seqsize - i];
    }
    free(sequencearray);
  }
```

I free my actual array (not my sequence) in main. I am curious as to what is causing the invalid read size of 8 because valgrind says there are no leaks. I am also curious as to where the 4 allocs come from as I only allocate for the acutal array, and the array for the sequence.

Comment: The invalid read means you're accessing memory out of bounds of some allocated array (or data).  It has nothing to do with whether or not there's a leak.  It says "8 bytes before"; you have an index of `-1` or something similar when accessing the array.  You need to compile your code with debugging enabled (`-g` assuming GCC or Clang is your compiler), both in creating the object file and linking.  Then you'll get line numbers for where the problem is, and it's usually pretty easy to find the trouble with the line numbers.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thats the thing, when I run gdb it just exits normally.

Comment: GDB is not Valgrind — they do different jobs. Valgrind is telling you there is a serious bug in your program. To get the maximum benefit from Valgrind, you must compile with debugging enabled. You then run that code with Valgrind, not GDB, to find out where you're code is going wrong. Since your code is not a complete program — it's not an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) (or MRE or whatever name SO now uses) nor an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) — it isn't clear that anyone else can reproduce your problem.

Comment: Are you sure that `Generate_2p3q_Seq()` does **not** return a `seqsize` of 0, so that the next line reading `sequencearray[seqsize - 1]` uses an index of `-1`?

Comment: @thebusybee Im sure of that. But I figured out what the problem was, if you're curious. These two lines: i += 1;
      interval = sequencearray[seqsize - i]; is where the -1 index invalid read comes from. I simply put an if statement there to check for it, and to break out if it is invalid.

Comment: OK. Now you could make this an answer and mark it, or delete your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured the answer to my question. These two lines cause the problem:

```
i += 1;
interval = sequencearray[seqsize - i];
```

This can be fixed with a simple if statement that breaks out if it is invalid (condition being that seqsize - i < 0, it is invalid, and you break.